# How to mask image with another image in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, mask, masking, bitmask

my issue is this, my users import an image with 
FileReference and I need to mask it and then send it to server.

My problem is this: I'm be able do keep the filereference event and 
transfer the image data into my canvas. I'm be able to send to server
the result of masking.

But I'm NOT be able to mask the image that my users have load in 
my canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add loaded bitmap to maskable container (e.g. Sprite). For exmaple:
Test.as

```
package {
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.net.FileReference;

public class Test extends Sprite {

    private var _fileReference:FileReference;
    private var _fileFilter:FileFilter;
    private var _loader:Loader;
    private var _imageContainer:Sprite;
    private var _mask:Sprite;
    private var _canvas:Sprite;

    public function Test() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageListener, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function addedToStageListener(event:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageListener);

        _fileReference = new FileReference();
        _fileReference.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectedListener, false, 0, true);
        _fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoadCompleteListener, false, 0, true);

        _fileFilter = new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png");

        _loader = new Loader();
        _canvas = new Sprite();

        _mask = new Sprite();
        var maskGraphics:Graphics = _mask.graphics;
        maskGraphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        maskGraphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 50);
        maskGraphics.endFill();

        _imageContainer = new Sprite();
        _imageContainer.mask = _mask;

        _canvas.addChild(_imageContainer);
        _canvas.addChild(_mask);

        addChild(_canvas);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickListener, false ,0, true);
    }

    private function mouseClickListener(event:Event):void {
        _fileReference.browse([_fileFilter]);
    }

    private function fileSelectedListener(event:Event):void {
        _fileReference.load();
    }

    private function fileLoadCompleteListener(event:Event):void {
        _loader.loadBytes(event.target.data);

        while(_imageContainer.numChildren) {
            _imageContainer.removeChildAt(0);
        }
        _imageContainer.addChild(_loader);
    }
}}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your quick reply... Your example it's very useful for me, but if I have an Image that have the mask information, for example this http://yfrog.com/5amaskblackp; how can integrate this image with _mask? Thanks so much Nicola

Answer (score 0):

This changes the situation, but not dramatically. Check out the modified solution:

```
package {
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.net.FileReference;

public class Test extends Sprite {

    private var _fileReference:FileReference;
    private var _fileFilter:FileFilter;
    private var _imageLoader:Loader;
    private var _maskLoader:Loader;
    private var _canvas:Sprite;

    private var _imageLoaded:Boolean = false;

    public function Test() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageListener, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function addedToStageListener(event:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageListener);

        _fileReference = new FileReference();
        _fileReference.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectedListener, false, 0, true);
        _fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoadCompleteListener, false, 0, true);

        _fileFilter = new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png");

        _imageLoader = new Loader();
        _imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoadCompleteListener, false, 0, true);
        _maskLoader = new Loader();
        _maskLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, maskLoadCompleteListener, false, 0, true);

        _canvas = new Sprite();
        addChild(_canvas);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickListener, false ,0, true);
    }

    private function mouseClickListener(event:Event):void {
        _fileReference.browse([_fileFilter]);
    }

    private function fileSelectedListener(event:Event):void {
        _fileReference.load();
    }

    private function fileLoadCompleteListener(event:Event):void {
        if (!_imageLoaded) {
            _imageLoader.loadBytes(event.target.data);
        } else {
            _maskLoader.loadBytes(event.target.data);
        }
    }

    private function imageLoadCompleteListener(event:Event):void {
        _imageLoaded = true;
    }

    private function maskLoadCompleteListener(event:Event):void {
        var imageBitmap:Bitmap = _imageLoader.content as Bitmap;
        var maskBitmap:Bitmap = _maskLoader.content as Bitmap;

        if (imageBitmap && maskBitmap) {
            var imageBitmapData:BitmapData = imageBitmap.bitmapData;
            var maskBitmapData:BitmapData = maskBitmap.bitmapData;

            var boundRectange:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, maskBitmap.width, maskBitmap.height);
            var destinationPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);

            var finalBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(maskBitmap.width, maskBitmap.height);
            finalBitmapData.copyPixels(imageBitmapData, boundRectange, destinationPoint, maskBitmapData, destinationPoint);
            var finalBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(finalBitmapData);

            while(_canvas.numChildren) {
                _canvas.removeChildAt(0);
            }
            _canvas.addChild(finalBitmap);
        }
    }
}}
```

First click on the stage allows you to select masked image. Second click allows you to select image, which contains the masking information (e.g. png file with transparency). Hope this helps.